# Reading InputStream into byte array and then converting to String problem

Tags: java, inputstream

I get the following log messages from this code, and I'm not sure why I am not getting the output in the string. Can someone advise if I am converting something incorrectly? `len` has a value, so I know the InputStream is good. `location` is also verified as good.

The files size I'm reading is 42.7 KB.

```
FileServices fs = new FileServices("");
InputStream in = fs.getInputStreamFromVault(location);

int len;
String strFileContents = "";

logger.info(logPrefix + "file1 ");
BufferedInputStream inBuff = new BufferedInputStream(in);
logger.info(logPrefix + "file2 ");
byte[] buf = new byte[564000];
logger.info(logPrefix + "file3 ");
int bytesRead = 0;
while ((len = inBuff.read(buf)) > 0) {
    logger.info(logPrefix + "file4 ");
    logger.info("len " + len); 
    
    strFileContents += new String(buf, 0, bytesRead); 
    logger.info("bytesRead " + bytesRead); 

    //String string = new String(buf, "UTF-8"); 
    //stream.write(buf, 0, len);
    logger.info("strFileContents " + strFileContents);
}
```

Log output

```
INFO  : [prefix] file1 
INFO  : [prefix] file2 
INFO  : [prefix] file3 
INFO  : [prefix] file4 
INFO  : len 43681
INFO  : bytesRead 0
INFO  : strFileContents
```

Comment: You're assigning the bytes read to `len`, but then use `bytesRead`, which is always 0 to create the string. BTW: You're approach could fail with UTF-8, because you might have a character that straddles two reads.

Answer (score 3):

The first problem in this code is that you never assigned anything to `bytesRead`.

But if you fix this, you still fundamentally read the text file the wrong way, because you're trying to manually decode `byte[]` to `String` in basically arbitrary chunks. That works fine if the text happens to only ever encode one character in exactly one byte. But as soon as you use a wide encoding (such as UCS-2) or a variable-length encoding (such as UTF-8 and UTF-16), this is prone to errors (which would introduce unnecessary decoding problems).

The correct way to read text from an `InputStream` is to wrap it in an [`InputStreamReader`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/io/InputStreamReader.html):

```
InputStream in = fs.getInputStreamFromVault(location);
Reader inReader = new InputStreamReader(in, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

StringBuilder contentBuilder = new StringBuilder();
char[] buf = new char[64*1024]; //arbitrary buffer size
int charsRead;
while ((charsRead = inReader.read(buf)) > 0) {
    contentBuilder.append(buf, 0, charsRead);
}

String strFileContents = contentBuilder.toString();
logger.info("strFileContents " + strFileContents);
```

Note that this also replaces string concatenation with the use of a `StringBuilder` which probably doesn't matter for such a small file, but is still a good habit to get into, because string concatenation in a loop is [a bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18561424/using-for-strings-in-a-loop-is-it-bad-practice/18561542).

Last but not least this *also* makes sure to specify the encoding to use instead of depending on the platform default encoding.

Comment: `Reader.read()` returns `-1` when the end of the stream is reached.

Comment: contentBuilder.append

Comment: @saka1029: that is correct. Do you propose something is wrong about my code? (Edit: fixed two typos).

Comment: AHH, very good! Works. (after I corrected typos ;)) Very educational in input streams which is a fog to me.

Comment: @user2568374: the fundamental thing to remember is: for binary data (or when you don't care about the actual content of the data) use `byte[]`/`InputStream`/`OutputStream` or `ByteBuffer`. If you are handling text data use `String`/`Reader`/`Writer` or `CharBuffer`. Only ever convert between the two by providing a character set. If you don't specify one, then it's very likely a bug.